# Select clause contains both clustered index and non clustered index, Which one will take highest priority?

Tags: oracle

```
clustered Index- id
non-clustered index- salary

select ename from employee where id=100 and salary>5000;
```

I want to know, Which one will get highest priority in oracle. 
Index unique scan or index range scan.

Please give suggestion.

Comment: Why don't you just get the explain plan and see what it says?

Comment: Are you talking about an "index organized table"? If yes, then **[edit]** your question and provide the full `create table` statement for the table. The term "clustered index" and "non-clustered" index don't really make sense

Comment: Please provide index DDL so we know what you mean by 'clustered' and 'non-clustered'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clustering has little to do with the selection.  The issue is which is more selective.

In this case, presumably `id` is more selective -- meaning that fewer rows match the `id` condition than the `salary` condition.

If you want to optimize the indexes for this query, then the best index is on `(id, salary, ename)`.

Comment: Regarding *the best index*: I understand `id, salary`, but - why `ename`?

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . That makes the index a covering index for the query.  That is, the SQL engine can use only the index and does not have to load the data pages.

Comment: It’s not strictly the most selective, it’s the one that produces the plan with the lowest cost